# Facebook Graph API: how do I retrieve my own posts?

Tags: c#, facebook-graph-api

I'm trying to write a program which retrieves my own posts and comments from facebook - I'm able to login and retrieve information about "me", but I got no idea how to get the posts I've written. I find the graph API documentation very confusing.

I'm using a c#/WPF assembly which lets me retrieve the information about me using:

```
  fbApp.GetAsync("me", (val) =>
  {
    var result = (IDictionary<string, object>)val.Result;
    Dispatcher.Invoke(System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherPriority.Normal,
                        new Action(delegate() { InfoBox.ItemsSource = result; }));
  });
```

Using which graph API I can retrieve my own posts and/or comments?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You simply retrieve your Feeds by a GET Request to

```
http://graph.facebook.com/me/feed
```

for comments

```
http://graph.facebook.com/[post-id]/comments
```

Comment: I tried, but I just get an empty result set (which can't be right, I've been posting a lot of stuff). I seem to miss something?

Comment: do you have a valid access token... if user had not set his feeds to be visible publicly then you need to have an access token.. like mine is public so you can see the results here:  http://graph.facebook.com/samajshekhar/feed

Comment: I have not used SDK but here is an example on how to parse json by using JavaScriptSerializer http://shekhar-pro.blogspot.com/2011/01/serializing-and-deserializing-data-from.html

Comment: You are right, I get a result for samajshekhar/feed. I don't have an access_token, I found no way to get one so far :(

Comment: to know how to get access token look here http://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication  they have good explanation with pictures

Comment: Ah yes, I found the access_token I needed.

Comment: Do you know how to get the oldest status message instead of the newest?

Comment: there is nothing as oldest in graph api..but you can always specify a time span in which you want to have your result set.. best will be to let the user select the time span and you fetch data within that time span.use since and untill query parameters.. like this url shows status since 1st december 2010  https://graph.facebook.com/samajshekhar/feed?limit=25&since=2010-12-01

Comment: there's  also link to paging in feeds for prev and next..use them smartly